# PowerShell progress Bar invocation fails in Runspace

Tags: wpf, powershell, progress-bar, runspace

I am creating a PowerShell script with a GUI, that copies user profiles from a selected source disk to a destination disk. I've created the GUI in XAML, with VS Community 2019.

My copy function is called from a runspace and works fine. I would like to put a progress bar inside this runspace so that it increases for each folder copied, but I can't figure out how.

Here is my runspace :

```
function RunspaceBackupData {
    $Runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
    $Runspace.ApartmentState = "STA"
    $Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"
    $Runspace.Open()
    $Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("syncHash",$syncHash)
    $Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("SelectedFolders",$global:SelectedFolders)
    $Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("SelectedUser",$global:SelectedUser)
     $Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("ReturnedDiskSource",$global:ReturnedDiskSource)
    $Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("ReturnedDiskDestination",$global:ReturnedDiskDestination)
    $code = {
        foreach ($item in $global:SelectedFolders) {
            copy-item -Path "$global:ReturnedDiskSource\Users\$global:SelectedUser\$item" -Destination "$global:ReturnedDiskDestination\Users\$global:SelectedUser\$item" -Force -Recurse
        }
    }

    $PSinstance = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($Code)
    $PSinstance.Runspace = $Runspace
    $job = $PSinstance.BeginInvoke()
}
```

Here is my event-handler :

```
$var_btnStart.Add_Click( {
    RunspaceBackupData -syncHash $syncHash -SelectedFolders $global:SelectedFolders -SelectedUser $global:SelectedUser -ReturnedDiskSource $global:ReturnedDiskSource -ReturnedDiskDestination $global:ReturnedDiskDestination 
})
```

Can you please help me ?

Comment: my understanding is that a runspace _does not have a UI_. it is designed to be non-interactive, so there is no place to show your progress bar. if you want so show such, you will need to manually set up some kind of communication between the runspace and the main thread.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the point :/

Comment: So what does "a progress bar inside this runspace" mean? Do you want to add a progress bar to your GUI that reflects the progress of the code in the runspace?

Comment: Yes exactly. Sorry if i didn't explained better

Comment: @OscarLoret - do a search for `powershell runspace return data` for ways to get info back from a runspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `$code` you need to keep the count, so I suggest a for-loop.

Inside the loop you can call the dispatcher in the window-object:

```
$syncHash.Window.Dispatcher.Invoke([action]{$syncHash.Progressbar.Value = [double] <code for finished percentage>}, "Normal")
```

I suspect you have window and progressbar in `$syncHash`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I already tried to use $syncHash.Window.Dispatcher.Invoke but it didn't worked at all. But now I don't remember if I've put my progressbar into the synchash variable... I only know Window is in. Do you think all of my controls should be in `$synchash` , even those that thaht won't interrract with the runspace ?

Comment: I really don't get it, i tried with a simple `$syncHash.Window.Dispatcher.invoke([action]{$syncHash.Window.Background='Black'},"Normal")` but the window doesn't turn black. Even with `$SyncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{ Form = $synchash.Window; ProgressBar = $synchash.ProgressBar })` put  earlier..

Answer (score 1):

Ok i've managed to get my progress bar working. First you gotta add it to your hashtable variable :
`$syncHash.ProgressBar = $syncHash.Window.FindName("ProgressBar")`
Then you can create your event-handler like this :

```
$var_btnStart.Add_Click( { 
$Runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$Runspace.ApartmentState = "STA"
$Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"
$Runspace.Open()
$Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("syncHash",$syncHash)
$Worker = 
[PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({$syncHash.ProgressBar.Dispatcher.Invoke([action] 
{$SyncHash.ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = $true }, "Normal")}
##YOUR CODE HERE
$syncHash.Error = $Error
$syncHash.ProgressBar.Dispatcher.Invoke([action]{$SyncHash.ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = $false }, "Normal")    
        })
    $Worker.Runspace = $Runspace
    $Worker.BeginInvoke()})
```

Note that in this example your progress bar is indeterminate, so it starts looping when you click on the button, and stops when you code ends.
Don't forget to dispose your runspace then :

`$Runspace.PowerShell.Close($Runspace) $Runspace.PowerShell.Dispose($Runspace)`